# openpyxl only reads first cell

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I was sent an XLSX file created on another computer that fails to open properly using `pandas.read_excel(filename,engine='openpyxl',sheet_name=None)`. There is a warning `Workbook contains no default style, apply openpyxl's default` and the objects returned are empty dataframes with only the first column name imported and an empty index for every sheet.

I then used openpyxl directly in the following manner:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename,read_only=True)
ws = wb['First Sheet']

for row in ws.rows:
  for cell in row:
    print(cell.value)
  # first_col_header

ws.calculate_dimension(force=True)
   # 'A1:A1'

print(ws['A1'].value)
   # first_col_header
print(ws['B1'].value)
   # second_col_header
print(ws['C1'].value)
   # third_col_header
print(ws['A2'].value)
   # first_val
print(ws['B2'].value)
   # sec_val
print(ws['C2'].value)
   # val_3
```

`calculate_dimension()` only pulls in the first cell, but I am able to get values from other cells.

I was thinking of manually iterating through to find the dimensions, but accessing cells appears to have a linear timing would be slow to find:

```
%%time
ws['A1'].value     # 5   ms
ws['A10'].value    # 50  ms
ws['A100'].value   # 250 ms
ws['A1000'].value  # 2.3 s
ws['A10000'].value # 22  s
```

The only workaround I found is that if I open the file and save it myself, pandas can import it. The issue is that I have many files, some very large, and cannot go through each to manually save.

Is there something I can do to make this work?

Comment: Might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64126185/openpyxl-cant-read-xlsx-file-but-if-i-save-the-file-it-opens

Comment: Whichever application produced the file made a mess of it. Use `ws.reset_dimensions()`.

Comment: Thanks. I was to set up something to iterate through the files, pull in each worksheet, `reset_dimensions()`, then `pd.read_excel` works. If you submit an answer, I can accept it. It still seems like there is a large amount of time to do this - ex. 300 seconds for 75,000 rows. Is there something I can do to speed this up?

Answer (score 2):

In the past we faced this kind of warning/behaviour with some Excel generated with Apache POI. As [Charlie Clark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2385133/charlie-clark) and you comment this can be fixed with *reset_dimensions()* method on Worksheet object of openpyxl.

More information on this Apache POI behaviour I comment can be found here:

https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1584