# pd.ExcelFile() of a .xlsx empty dataframe. Must open and save .xlsx for pd.ExcelFile() to work

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlsx

Title is a concise summary. I have a report, downloaded from Attentive. This report is saved as .xlsx in my downloads. I go to read this report with panda's ExcelFile() function and it gives the following warning:

```
UserWarning: Workbook contains no default style, apply openpyxl's default
  warn("Workbook contains no default style, apply openpyxl's default")
```

and the dataframe returns as

```
{'One-Time Messages': Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Date]
Index: []}
```

after using `.parse()`.

BUT

When I open the file, save it (overwriting the current), and close these functions work perfectly. I can say I see no issue with the .xlsx (it's not the Strict version) and nothing else seems to be changing but cannot verify the before until I open it so I suspect it's how it's downloaded and when it is opened the so-called style sheet is applied.

How might I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I met exactly the some problem,

It really took me a lot of time to find out why,

and finally it turns out to be the format incompability problem.

I posted my answer under another thread, hope it helps:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78136302/14054451